# Git extensions with personal access token from visual studio online

Tags: git, git-bash, azure-devops, git-extensions

Visual Studio Online has something called "personal access token". http://roadtoalm.com/2015/07/22/using-personal-access-tokens-to-access-visual-studio-online/

I have been using git extension but the only way to set up is username and password i think, or is there a way to do this with access token too?

I really don´t want to start using the git bash if I don´t have to.

Comment: In my first opinion, you can't use personal access token from VSO in Git extensions. However, can you share me the link to show which Git extensions you're working with (as I can find many Git extensions online)?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the goals is for Personal Access Tokens to function in a place where HTTP Basic authentication is required.  For example, Git clients.

As the web page you link to indicates:

> So when you now clone a Git repository you only have to fill in this token in the password box. Username can be empty or any value

So use any username you wish, and put the personal access token in Git Extensions' password field.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but came across in a search, so I'll share my situation for others.

I'm using Git Extensions and the Personal Access Token (PAT) works as a password with my email address as login username when trying to push or pull.

Strangely enough, now I need two logins. It asks me for my general Microsoft login in a special Microsoft-style dialog box, then it asks me for VSTS login details in the Git Extensions text dialog as well. I use my regular email/password combo in the first one and my email/PAT in the second one.

This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the Git Extension tool you posted above, it is not possible to connect with personal access token, you have to use username and password.

Visual Studio Online uses the OAuth 2.0 protocol to authorize your app for a user and generate an access token. However, right now, Visual Studio Online only support the web server app to implement OAuth for Visual Studio Online.

Please check this link for the details: 
https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth

Comment: do you know any other version of Git Extension that works with this token?